# Regex searching for number and letter combination optional brackets

Tags: regex

I need to get a regex that will find a match of a single lower case a-z character followed by 5 numbers that is either:

- at the start of a line
- at the end of a line
- surrounded by () or []
- surrounded by whitespace

So the following results are expected:

a12345 MATCH

(a12345) MATCH

[a12345] MATCH

text a12345 MATCH

aa12345 NO MATCH

At the moment I have this `(?<=[])]*)[a-z]{1}[0-9]{5}(?=[])]*)` but it is not working for all scenarios, for example it sees aa12345 and a12345a as being matches when I don't want them to.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**
Apologies I should have mentioned this is for .NET c#

Comment: What about `[a12345) TEXT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your should mention programming language.

Following solution is for **PCRE**.

**Regex:** `((?<=[\[( ])|^)[a-z]\d{5}((?=[\]\) ])|$)`

**Explanation:**

1. `((?<=[\[( ])|^)` checks for preceding brackets, whitespaces **OR** beginning.
2. `[a-z]\d{5}` checks for alphabet followed by 5 digits.
3. `((?=[\]\) ])|$)` checks for succeeding brackets, whitespaces **OR** end of line.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kuRmJM/2)

Comment: Thanks for this, it was very close to what I wanted, I've changed to this and seems to be good now ((?<=[\[( ])|^)[a-z]\d{5}((?=[\]\) ])|$)

Comment: @NAJ: Why aren't you **escaping** `[` and `]` in lookarounds ?

Comment: sorry that appears to be the editor changing the comment it should be this: `((?<=[\[( ])|^)[a-z]\d{5}((?=[\]\) ])|$)`

Comment: @NAJ: Careful with last `*`. I hope my solution helps. ☺

Comment: thanks yes I think that's what I am after now, the last * was removed otherwise it thought text a12345a was a match

Comment: @NAJ: That case wasn't included in question. I will improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
(\[[a-z]\d{5}\])|(\([a-z]\d{5}\))|(\b[a-z]\d{5}\b)
```

Comment: close, it is including the brackets in the match though which I don't want